# Why might I be getting a 500 Error when using Python Requests, but not using cURL

Tags: php, python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to work on a basic implementation of the Synchroteam API using python's requests. I was able to establish a connection using cURL as a proof of concept and get all the data I wanted, but using requests I am able to get into the site with my credentials, but all I get is:

```
500
text/html; charset=utf-8
https://apis.synchroteam.com/Api/v1/user/list

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        An error occurred while processing your request.
    </h2>
</body>
</html>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When using curl with this line everything returns the correct info:

```
curl -u domain:APIKEY -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://apis.synchroteam.com/Api/v1/user/List
```

My small bit of python code is this:

```
import requests


apiurl = 'https://apis.synchroteam.com/Api/v1/user/list'
login = ("domain", "APIKEY")
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

def run():
    r = requests.get(apiurl, auth=login, headers=headers)

    print r.status_code
    print r.headers['Content-type']
    print r.url
    print r.text

run()
```

All of the Synchroteam documentation has examples in PHP, but I can't see any reason why i wouldn't be able to use python.
The docs are here: http://api.synchroteam.com/rest.php

Any insight would be great, I really hope its just something small I'm missing.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Accept:` header as well?

Comment: I have not. Any idea what I should be setting it to accept? I'm not sure what its currently getting hung up on. Sorry for the basic question, its my first time using any HTTP or external APIs

Comment: UPDATE: I had not tried this. I realize now this is similar to the Curl line. Thank you so much, this has been bothering me for hours.

Answer (score -1):

This is the Python code I generate using Postman. I'm sure it will help you!

```
import requests

url = "https://apis.synchroteam.com/Api/v1/User/list"

payload = "{\n    \"status\":\"1\"\n}"
headers = {
'content-type': "application/json",
'accept': "application/json",
'authorization': "Basic ZGVtbzoxMjEyOThucDIwMDM=",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'postman-token': "1a3839b6-db5b-0c07-be1a-2816f491476c"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Just change the Auth!
Nick

Comment: It doesn't give a clue about the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was able to figure this out with the help of ig0774. All I needed was headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'} and that fixed everything. I may have to look into doing some more advanced headers later.